# Split a string into multiple text inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, split

I need a way for users to edit the value of a field that is Vertex 3D.
The value is stored as a string, but I want to display it to the user as three separate input fields for them to edit.

I need a way to split the string by spaces, and then show each index in a separate input. I tried doing with this a filter, like this:

```js
myApp.filter('split', function() {
  return function(input, splitChar, splitIndex) {
    return input.split(splitChar)[splitIndex];
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="value | split:' ':0"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="value | split:' ':1"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="value | split:' ':2"/>
```

But you cannot assign a value to a filter so it throws an error.

What would be the correct way to achieve this? TIA!

Comment: Split the value in your controller and store each part on the model

Comment: Filters are for output only. You need to write a directive that uses the `ngModelController`

Comment: it's very easy to do it, but it's not good practice to bind a model to a run time created array element,  it will be better if you do the following : 
var parts  = stringVal.split('');
var x  = parts[0], y = parts[1], z = parts[2];

and then in your inputs, bind each for it's corresponding value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommand to split your string by spaces and show each part in an input:

**Angular variables**

```
$scope.myString = 'My awesome text';
$scope.arr = $scope.myString.split(/[ ]+/);
```

**HTML inputs**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="arr[0]" />
<input type="text" ng-model="arr[1]" />
<input type="text" ng-model="arr[2]" />
```

---

[**Try it on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/z0drfcg0/).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better, readable and faster than filters make something like this:

**Controller:**

```
...
let vertexParts = vertex.split(' ');
$scope.vertex3d = {x: vertexParts[0], y: vertexParts[1], z: vertexParts[2]};
....
$scope.saveVertex = function() {
    myVertexService.save([$scope.vertex3d.x, $scope.vertex3d.y, $scope.vertex3d.z].join(' '));
};
...
```

**Template:**

```
<label>
    X: <input type="text" ng-model="vertex3d.x"/>
</label>
<label>
    Y: <input type="text" ng-model="vertex3d.y"/>
</label>
<label>
    Z: <input type="text" ng-model="vertex3d.z"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
var vertexApp = angular.module('vertexApp', []);

vertexApp.controller('vertexCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.coordsString = 'xxx yyy zzz';
    $scope.coords = $scope.coordsString.split(' ');

    $scope.$watch('coords[0]', function () {
        $scope.coordsString = $scope.coords.join(' ');
    });

    $scope.$watch('coords[1]', function () {
        $scope.coordsString = $scope.coords.join(' ');
    });

    $scope.$watch('coords[2]', function () {
        $scope.coordsString = $scope.coords.join(' ');
    });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="vertexApp">
    <div ng-controller="vertexCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="coords[0]" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="coords[1]" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="coords[2]" />
        <br />
        New model value: {{coordsString}}
    </div>
</div>
```